# Azure Data Lake Store: Request Was Unauthorized When Writing to ADLS from Data Factory in a Different Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

The issue is that I am unable to write to an Azure Data Lake Store in one Azure subscription from an Azure Data Factory in another subscription without enabling read/write/execute access for ALL USERS AND GROUPS in the Data Lake Store.  I know that I set up the authorization properly in the ADF Linked Service for the Data Lake Store too, so that is not the issue.  Here are the details:

I have an Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) created by me under my company's main Azure subscription (in this sub I am a Co-admin and have access to everything except creating/modifying other users).

I have an Azure Data Factory (ADF) under my own MSDN-related Azure subscription and I am trying to use the ADLS as the sink for a copy activity.

I use the same login to access both Azure subscriptions in to portal, and when I run my pipeline I get a (403) Forbidden error with `ErrorCode=UserErrorAdlsUnauthorizedAccess`.

**What I have tried so far**:

I followed the instructions here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-store-secure-data/ and added myself to the AAD group.  However when I went to add the group as an owner of the data store, Azure could not find the group so I was unable to add it.

**AAD Group**:

[image: Azure Active Directory Group in the data lake store subscription]

**Failure to find AAD Group**:

[image]

I also tried adding myself as a user in the OWNER role on the data store (via the Users blade) and I have read/write/execute access in the Access blade of the data lake store.  There was also another developer added as an Owner, and had read/write/execute access but the same results were produced.

**Me assigned as a user to data lake store**:

[image]

**Me granted access to file system of data lake store**:

[image]

Both of these result in the same 403 unauthorized error when I try to run the ADF pipeline or re-run any of the failed slices.  The only thing that has worked for me is to enable READ/WRITE/EXECUTE access for all users and groups:

[image]

I tried with write/execute and with just write, but neither of those combinations worked.  When I enable that and re-run my failed slice/s now, everything completes successfully and data is written to the Data Lake Store.

Is there any way to write to a data lake store from another subscription without opening up access like this?  I would think so due to the fact that you can specify a subscription in the Data Lake Store Linked Service, but so far I haven't been able to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the "subscriptionId" of the Azure Data Lake Store when creating the Data Lake Store Linked Service, and then click "Authorize" to pop up the interactive prompt (in this order). Can you confirm you had tried to create the Linked Service in the order above?

Comment: Your reply is more of a conversation than an answer.  This would have been a good response as a comment

Comment: Yes, that is the second sentence of my post.  Not trying to be rude, but I wrote that sentence to avoid this answer.  Also, if I hadn't properly authorized then it would never work but as stated above, it works if I open up the file system access on the data lake store.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I have reached out to see if this is a bug on our end. We might need some account specific details to help pinpoint the issue. If you want to reach out to me at ZHICTAN{at}MICROSOFT{dot}COM so we can follow up that would help expedite the investigation.

Comment: Following up again, we were able to repro what you're seeing above and are looking into what's causing the bug.